Convergence of square root of n series
I'm having trouble determining the convergence/divergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}}$$
I tried to solve it with the comparison test, yet I wasn't able to find the correct substitute:
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n^{n+1}}}=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}$$
$$\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}< \frac{1}{n}$$
Should I use different criteria, or are there better elements to substitute in the inequality?

Hint ... $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{-(n+1)/n}}{1/n} = ?$$

$1 \le n^{1/n} \le e^{1/e} < 1.445$ so $\dfrac{1}{1.445, n}<\dfrac{1}{n^{(n+1)/{n}}} \le \dfrac{1}{n}$ would give you the answer

Hint: $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}$. Now use the limit comparison test with a well known series.
